# CastError with dates in Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, date, mongoose

I've got a schema that includes dates:

```
const dateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  resortName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  runName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  weatherConditions: String,
  windConditions: String,
  snowConditions: String,
  runTime: Number,
  runCrowded: Boolean,
  runJumps: Boolean,
  runNotes: String,
});
```

And I'm seeding my DB with some dummy JSON:

```
[{
    "resortName": "Winter Park",
    "date": "2022-04-15T09:31:03.503Z",
    "runName": "Mary Jane",
    "runDifficulty": "blue",
    "weatherConditions": "cloudy",
    "windConditions": "windy",
    "snowConditions": "icy",
    "runTime": 13,
    "runCrowded": true,
    "runJumps": false,
    "runNotes": "Crowded run, patches of ice in middle of slope"
}]
```

I created the following route:

```
dateRouter.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Date.find({}).then((dates) => {
    res.json(dates);
  });
});
```

, but when I attempt to visit the route I get the following error:

```
 C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4697
  const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: 'dates' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "Resort"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4697:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4796:15)
    at C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\controllers\resortControllers.js:21:23    
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:360:14)
    at param (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:371:14) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: `"{ _id: 'dates' }"`,
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: { _id: 'dates' },
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
      at new BSONTypeError (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
      at new ObjectId (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:65:23)
      at castObjectId (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:19:14)
      at ObjectId.cast (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:247:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1189:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1623:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1613:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1590:20)
      at cast (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:288:34)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\projects\slope-notes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5119:12),
  valueType: 'Object'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried seeding your DB with `"date": ISODate("2022-04-15T09:31:03.503Z")`? It seems that you are currently assigning string value.

Comment: It's definitely assigning as a string because if I change it to "random string" in the seed it will show up as such in my MongoDB. When I try to change my JSON seed to 
"date": ISODate("2022-04-15T09:31:03.503Z")
it gives an error as that's not proper JSON.

Comment: How do you populate the DB? The ISODate syntax should work for mongosh and common MongoDB clients. Or you may try `"date": {"$date": "2022-04-15T09:31:03.503Z"}`

Comment: --EDIT: I added this new format to the JSON and it appears to have seeded as a Date value---  Apologies - I'm very new to this. Currently I'm populating the DB through a JSON file (Second code block above) and then running a seed.js file with node. 
`const Dates = require("../models/date");
const seedDate = require("./dates.json");
Dates.deleteMany({})
  .then(() => {
    return Dates.collection.insertMany(seedDate);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("dates seeded");
    process.exit();
  });`

Comment: So your issue is solved by seeding the DB as a Date value using the format suggested?

Comment: Yes, your format suggestion fixed the seeding issue - it appears as my original issue is that my secondary express route is getting stuck on my primary route! The original error was solved as my `resortRouter.get("/:id")` for my first controller is being triggered by my second controller: `dateRouter.get("/dates")`. I had to change the order of my controllers in `index.js` to bypass this routing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first I believe you have a naming conflict, `Date` is a reserved word in javascript/node, if you change the collection name the issue should resolve itself

but you may have a better experience with the following:

```js
dateRouter.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  // (change Date to a different name)
  const records = await Date.find({})
  res.json(records)
})
```

Comment: Would `async` and `await` prevent the `const records = ...` from returning undefined?

Comment: i believe whats happening then is that there is a naming conflict, `Date` is a reserved word in javascript/node, if you change the collection name the issue should resolve itself

Comment: I did change the collection name and it seems to be performing better. Rather than doing async/await I'm using res.locals to good effect. Thank you!